# Hiding div if text/phrase matches in another element? (css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, hide

So I once in a while create UserStyle themes for websites as CSS theme over rides. Now I am creating one so I can hide videos in the subscriptions main feed on Youtube, but I have ran into a problem. I know how to normally make an element change its style if you hover over another as an example but I tried to combine the use with the following:

```
[data-context-item-title*="Miley"] * > [class="feed-item-container  legacy-style vve-check"]
```

I have tried many variations but do not seem to have had any luck. I considered trying to find and use a Jquery injector extension for chrome, none unfortunately that I can find will not only inject but save so when you load the page again. I would really appreciate it if anyone can shed some light or even better, have a solution for my problem(migrane). If the solution is possible, I would prefer it to be CSS and not jquery.

What I use at the moment (blocks all but the video container / http://prntscr.com/2fkmve):

```
[data-original-html^="Miley"],
[data-original-html*="Miley"],
[data-context-item-title*="Miley"] *,
[data-context-item-title*="Miley"],
[data-context-item-title="Miley"]
{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Do you want the hide the whole division that contains the video matching above parameters ?

Comment: yes, the container as well, image: http://prntscr.com/2fkmve

Comment: There is no solution for it using css2.1 and css3 as far as I know but this can be easily done using jquery prev() method , to get the previous element .

Comment: is their a jquery extension for chrome that will not just inject but save for websites?

Comment: I found an extension that lets you customize pages with jquery, yet to test it, only extension that I have found. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jscript-tricks/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod?hl=en